# Puppeteer .innerHTML on element returns undefined

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I've been scraping a bunch of websites lately and some of them work just fine, while on others I encounter problems.
`

```
const { url, selectors } = WebsiteUtils

const getData = async (url) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setViewport({
        height: 20000,
        width: 1500,
    })
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })

    const link = page.$(selectors.link)
    return link.innerHTML
}

console.log(await getData(url))
```

`

In this case, the 'selectors.link' is literally just 'ul' as there's a bunch of them in the page. I already tried to wait for the selector (.waitForSelector), I used page.evaluate instead of .$, even put a 5 secs timeout to make sure everything was loaded. The HTML is not even inside an iframe, it's a really straightforward page. When I get to this I'm pretty much out of options.

The output here is **undefined**,
if i just log 'link' I get **ElementHandle {}**

Update:
I figured this out. Unlike what i previously wrote, iframe were indeed present in the page although they were not present in the HTML of the devtools.
I just spotted them running **page.frames()** and access the content of the individual frames with **frame.$eval()**

Comment: Can you check for the response code? Maybe you're getting a 4xx response from this specific site or a general connection timeout. What do you get when you `console.log(page)`?

Comment: I'm surprised this works at all. Isn't the correct pattern `return page.$eval(selectors.link, el 
 => el.innerHTML)`? This code leaks a resource and hangs the process because `browser.close()` is never run. I suggest that being in a `finally` block.

Comment: @ggorlen on puppeteer docs it lists both the .$ method and the .$eval method. One stores the element in a variable, the other passes it as first argument of the pageFunction. However i tried in all ways. I don't have browser.close() here becuase I'm not running the browser headless and just close it myself, if I were to publish the code I'd include it.
I've scraped quite a bit of websites but this one really puzzles me

Comment: I understand that, but Puppeteer handles have no such `.innerHTML` property. That's a browser DOM node property only accessible via `eval` and family. Anyway, without the site I can't really offer any help. Maybe you're being blocked, maybe the element is loading slowly and needs to be waited for, maybe the element is in a shadow DOM or iframe... it's anyone's guess.

Comment: If you're not convinced, feel free to run these two lines of code which log undefined: `await page.setContent("<p>foo</p>"); console.log((await page.$("p")).innerHTML);` while this logs `foo` as expected: `console.log(await page.$eval("p", el => el.innerHTML));`

Comment: @ggorlen. Yep that makes perfect sense, you're right. Anyway I eventually got it working just by looking for iframes in the page and evaluating them, and they were there even though they were not shown in the devtools HTML. Any idea why btw?Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can't really say what the problem is without running and seeing the page.